# Deleted Dawnguard DLC & profile - can I re-download the Dawnguard DLC for free?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360, skyrim-dawnguard

Okay, so here's the problem: I deleted Dawnguard off the download history off my Xbox 360 & I deleted the profile that I downloaded it from too. So can I re-download the Dawnguard DLC for free or do I have to pay for it all over?

Note: I did not save the profile on a hard drive & deleted the profile off my download history.

Answer (score 2):

You can redownload Dawngaurd with the profile that purchased it. No other. If you have deleted the profile redownload it, go to the Skyrim DLC and it should still be ticked as owned and with no price if your signed into the profile that originally purchased it.